# typescript issue to copy to clip-board => different result for chrome and mozilla browsers

Tags: angular, google-chrome, mozilla

I have an issue related to copy the content of textarea component into clipboard, and I get two different results when executing code on mozilla browser and chrome:

Here my typescript code:

'HTML':

```
<button (click)="copyContent(content_txt)">
<i class="fa fa-copy">
</i>
```

'Ts':

copyContent(content_txt){

```
content_txt.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
content_txt.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
```

}

the resuls:
- Mozilla: - just click on button: select + copy all selected elements on textarea
- Chrome: you have to select then click the button to detect copied elements.

Thanks for any tips to add or to correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
copyContent(content_txt: string){
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.value = content_txt;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this third party module to copy the text.

"https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-text-to-clipboard"